# Dialog not closing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a popup window where you can add something to a database. However, I get errors in the console when you click in the Name-field, saying:

```
VM247 1:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'result' of undefined
```

If you still enter text/numbers in the boxes and press save, the popupwindow just loads. However when you refresh the view, the entity is saved to the database.

Anyone knows the cause for this?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input ng-model="csc.user.newEntry.Name" onfocus="csc.saveData.result = ''" />
        <div ng-messages="csc.user.newEntry.Name.$error" ng-show="csc.saveData.result < 0">
            <div>Duplicate Name</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
saveEntry: function () {
vm.savingActivated = true;
vm.saveData =  EntriesResource.save(vm.user.newEntry,
    () => {
        vm.savingActivated = false;
        console.log(vm.saveData.result);
        if (vm.saveData.result > 0) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("EntriesUpdated");
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a property of an object inside you template logic, the object itself must exist in the time of referring to its members.
When you focus into input you're creating it using `onfocus`. 
initialize it before or try change the expression in your `ngShow` to use the object itself instead of its properties.

```
saveEntry: function () {
       vm.savingActivated = true;

       // intializeing
       vm.saveData = {};

       vm.saveData =  EntriesResource.save(vm.user.newEntry,
            () => {
                vm.savingActivated = false;
                console.log(vm.saveData.result);
                if (vm.saveData.result > 0) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("EntriesUpdated");
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but it didn't work. i tried initalizing it before the saveData, but i still get the error "Cannot set property 'result' of undefined".

Comment: Vividly the problem is it's trying to set property `result` to `csc.saveData` while it's not defined yet. but I don't know which line exactly throws this error, so I can not tell which is the required line to initialize the object before that. Of course I had a mistake that I fixed in my answer

Comment: Oh, if you first set the `result` then call the `saveEntery` function, then initialization must be outside and before this function

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the TypeError. However, the dialog refuses to close when you click Save. However, it is saved to the database and is shown in the view when you refresh it. Got any idea there?

Comment: well, in this part of code there is nothing seem to be wrong about dialog. do you get any errors? is $mdDialog returning expected object in your console.log? does the interpreter reach that line?